# Remove everything from a text file between ":" and "\n"

Tags: text-processing

I have a big text file (263 lines) that contains lines something like these:

```
image_name.jpg: *lots of spaces* JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 96x96, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1024x768, frames 3 \n
image_name.jpg: *lots of spaces* JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, comment: "CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 70", progressive, precision 8, 960x540, frames 3 \n
image_name.png: *lots of spaces* PNG image data, 752 x 760, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced \n
```

How can I remove all the text between ***:*** and ***\n*** at once?

Comment: `sed -e 's/:.*//'` (or `'s/:.*/:/'` if you want to keep the `:`).

Comment: is this substring `*newline (\n)*` occurs literally?

Comment: I spent a minute staring at the screen trying to decide which one of five or so text-processing tools would be "easiest" in this case... :)

Comment: You have multiple `:` in some lines, for instance `comment: "CREATOR:` in second line. How that should be handled ?  Is your goal to get only the stuff *before the first : in line* ?

Comment: What do you mean "something like these"? Are they or are they not as you describe? If the lines are not as you describe, then there's not much anyone can do to help.

Comment: @jpmc26, it probably means that those are examples, not all possible input lines, there are likely to be others. We can't really expect anyone to present the expected inputs in a formal grammar or some such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[With `cut`:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html)

```
cut -d: -f1 file
```

[With `sed`:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

```
sed -e 's/:.*//' file
```

[With `awk`:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

```
awk -F: '{print $1}' file
```

With [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control) or [many](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%209.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) [BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/grep.1) [`grep`s](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?grep%201%20NetBSD-current) (but not POSIX `grep`):

```
grep -o '^[^:]*' file
```

`cut` is the shortest one.

If you want to modify the file in-place, your `sed` may have an option `-i` that does so - but how exactly that works depends on your platform. Otherwise, `> file2 && mv file2 file` on the end of any of them will work.

[Alternatively, with `ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html), in-place everywhere:

```
printf ',s/:.*/\nw\n' | ed file
```

Answer (score 2):

ObPerl:

```
perl -pe 's/:.*//' file
```

or in-place, leaving a backup file:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/:.*//' file
```